# Sparx Enterprise Architect DocumentGenerator does not honour TaggedValues on Stereotype or values from SetProjectConstants and ReplaceField

Tags: enterprise-architect

maybe someone can help me on this. I am trying to generate a document via the [`DocumentGenerator`](https://sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/14.0/automation/document_generator_interface_class.html) interface. All in all this works well, except that the `DocumentGenerator` does not replace the **Report Constants** with actual values (which are defined on the `report package` *stereotype*.

[image: Definition of Report Package]

This is the general flow of the document creation code (which generally works):

```
var gen = Repository.CreateDocumentGenerator();
gen.SetProjectConstant("ReportName", "My Project");
gen.NewDocument(string.Empty);
gen.ReplaceField("ReportName", "My Project");
gen.InsertCoverPageDocument(tags[REPORT_COVERPAGE]);
gen.InsertBreak(DocumentBreak.breakPage);
gen.InsertTOCDocument(tags[REPORT_TOC]);
gen.InsertBreak(DocumentBreak.breakPage);
gen.DocumentPackage((int)nativeId, 0, template);
gen.SaveDocument(fileName, DocumentType.dtDOCX);
```

I tried `ReplaceField` and `SetProjectConstant` both and one at a time before and after calls to `NewDocument`/`InsertCoverPageDocument`:

[image: Project Constants defined]

[image: Document CoverPage Template]

[image: Generated Document CoverPage]

- Strangely there is one constant that is being replaced: `ReportSummary`.
- When I run the document generator via "F8" all constants are being replaced correctly.
- Other project constants are being replaced correctly.

I can reproduce the behaviour on EA v14.1.1429 and v12.0.1215.

Does someone have a hint for further troubleshooting? Thanks in advance!

========== UPDATE ==========

- When I use `ReplaceField` at the end (before the actual call to `SaveDocument` the following **Report Constants** get replaced: `{ReportTitle}` and `{ReportName}`
- I discovered some workaround: when I manually remove the predefined `{Report~}` constants from the template and re-add them as **Project Constants**, their values get replaced correctly.

I will examine this further and give an update as

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some further investigation on this and came to the following conclusion and workaround (as I have received no comments or answers on this):

- I deleted all references to **ReportConstants** in my EA templates and replaced them by **ProjectConstants** with the same name.
- In my code where I want to generate the documentation I (re)set all **ProjectConstants** with the actual values via `SetProjectConstant` and additionally added a call to `ReplaceField` to replace the constants with the actual values.
- The previous mentioned calls are inserted directly before the call to `SaveDocument` document.

```cs
tags.ForEach(t =>
{
  if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(t.Key)) return;
  generator.SetProjectConstant(t.Key, t.Value);
  generator.ReplaceField(t.Key, t.Value);
});

generator.SaveDocument(fileName, DocumentType.dtDOCX);
```

If someone comes up with a better resonse or explanation for the behaviour I am happy to accept this as answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have also found that when you call ReplaceField on these project constants in a CoverPage template, the formatting defined in the template is overwritten. It seems that some of the SetProjectConstant calls actually set the values as you would expect, and the rest do not.. hence the need to call both sets of APIs.